# Using lookahead, how to ensure at least 4 alphanumeric chars are included + underscores

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make sure that at least 4 alphanumeric characters are included in the input, and that underscores are also allowed.

The regular-expressions tutorial is a bit over my head because it talks about assertions and success/failure if there is a match.

```
^\w*(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})$
```

**my understanding:**

`\w` --> alphanumeric + underscore

`*` --> matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times ( so, this means it can be any character that is alphanumeric/underscore, correct?)

`(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})` --> looks ahead of the previous characters, and if they include at least 4 alphanumeric characters, then I'm good.

Obviously I'm wrong on this, because regex101 is showing me no matches.

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{4,}$` - input is a string of *4 or more* symbols each of them is either letter or digit or underscore? `[a-zA-Z0-9_]{4,}` - input *contains* a sequence of *4 or more* symbols each of them is either letter or digit or underscore?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko hey thanks for taking the time.. i want to make sure the input doesnt turn out to be something like ```___h8``` but have something like ```hello99____```

Comment: So, input *must start* from letter, and *must contain* at  least 3 chars each o them are either letter, digits or underscores? `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,}$`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko i dont care what it starts with or ends with, it can be as long as possible - but i would like there to be at least 4 alphanumerics..so that lets say its 6 total characters only 2 of them can be underscore

Comment: You can try *atomic* groups: `^(?>_*[a-zA-Z0-9]_*){4}[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$`: we ensure *4* fragments each of them contain `1` letter or digit

Comment: @DmitryBychenko this works! (but i have no idea how) i will try to break it down piece by piece

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern `^\w*(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})$` does not match because:

- `^\w*` Matches optional word characters from the start of the string, and if there are only word chars it will match until the end of the string
- `(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})` The positive lookahead is true, if it can assert 4 consecutive alphanumeric chars to the right from the current position. The `\w*` allows backtracking, and can backtrack 4 positions so that the assertion it true.
- But the `$` asserts the end of the string, which it can not match as the position moved 4 steps to the left to fulfill the previous positive lookahead assertion.

---

Using the lookahead, what you can do is assert 4 alphanumeric chars preceded by optional underscores.

If the assertion is true, match 1 or more word characters.

```
^(?=(?:_*[a-zA-Z0-9]){4})\w+$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, asser what is to the right is

  - `(?:_*[a-zA-Z0-9]){4}` Repeat 4 times matching optional `_` followed by an alphanumeric char
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters (which includes the `_`)
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/62GaX9/1)

Comment: thanks for taking the time, would the following work for atleast 4 alphnumeric and any underscore OR number:  ```/^(?:_*[0-9]*[A-Za-z][0-9]*_*){4,}$/``` i tried to do this with ur logic, hopefully it works

Answer (score 3):

You want 4 or more alphanumeric characters, surround by any number of underscores (use `^` and `$` to ensure it match's the whole input ):

```
^(_*[a-zA-Z0-9]_*){4,}$
```

Comment: Please, add *anchors*: `^` and `$`; otherwise, `!!!!!abcd!!!!!` and alike will match

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using *atomic* groups `(?>...)`, please see [regex tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) for details

```
 ^(?>_*[a-zA-Z0-9]_*){4,}$
```

to ensure **4** or more fragments each of them containing letter or digit.

**Edit:** If regex *doesn't support* atomic, let's try use just groups:

```
  ^(?:_*[A-Za-z0-9]_*){4,}$
```